# Aggregate in Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am new to pymongo and trying a few different things out. One question I want to ask is: How to perform aggregation over a few million records?

Each document following dicts:

```
{'_id': [id], 'date_of_addition': [unix_time_stamp], etc.}
```

What I want to aggregate in the above one is how many records were added per date?

Any hint, ideas, thanks.

Comment: Start here: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation framework works exactly the same in the shell that in pyMongo, there's no difference at all. You only need to be aware of datatypes in some cases, let's imagine you're aggregating in the shell using a date range

```
... { $match : { $gte : ISODate('2013-12-01T10:00:00Z') } } ...
```

You need to use a datetime in pyMongo and enclose your keywords with double quote:

```
... { "$match" : { "$gte" : datetimevar } } ...
```

Despite of that you need to practise a lot with aggregation framework and learn how to do it in the shell. Your question is too generic and it seems you don't have knowledge of aggregation framework at all. If you come from the SQL world whichever engine you used to work with I suggest you to spend MORE time with aggregation framework and follow the classes online. You don't probably have deep knowledge of how aggregation is made inside of SQL too because it's normal, SQL (any engine) solves the issues for you and magically returns results. Not the case in a non-SQL database. Think about aggregation as a pipeline where you apply different transformations to your data:

I have my data so:

1. I filter records I don't want to aggregate
2. I group by a field I need
3. I filter again from this group to remove some results
4. I sort them
5. I limit the result to N records

That's a small example, just check the docs and also follow classes [online](http://education.mongodb.com)